# Dynamic confirmation box in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to take confirmation from the user and as per the user response we want to execute the code.

We have situation as we are doing some operation on the user inputs. 
As per the user input we are showing confirmation box to the user for his confirmation.
If user clocked on yes then we have to execute different code and if user say no then we have to execute difference code.

Currently we have used MessageBox.Show(""), but this is no good.

```
     if(confirmation yes)
     {
         //execute this code.
     }
     else
     {
         //execute this.
     }
```

Please suggest.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show("")` is not good? Its specific to Winforms, In ASP.NET there is nothing  like MessageBox.

Comment: Read about Javascript's confirm().

Comment: Hi If i am using JavaScript then it is showing popup before starting back-end operation. We are executing query on back end and on the basis of user confirmation we have to move for further process.

Answer (score 0):

instead of MessageBox simply use javascript

```
if(confirm('Are you Sure'))
 {  
    //execute code here or call your server method for 'Yes'
 }
else
{
    //execute code here or call your server method for 'No'
}
```

Comment: Hi Akshay, thannks for your comment. Can you please share the real example. Because i am little confuse as how to get true/false value from confirmation box.

Comment: hi King  [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/5sn97tju/)  you will find a simple example

Comment: Hi Akshay, Same thing i want to use in back end (C#).
I am checking values in the database on the basis of DB value for particular user i want confirmation box.

Comment: ok here is example with confirm extender if you want it from server side [click this](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/aspnet-ajax-confirmbuttonextender.html)